# How to move one y label to the right

Tags: positioning, labels, pst-plot

As you see the image below, the label "4" on y-axis gets in the way with the plot.  How do I move it to the right?  I tried adding the following statement:

```
psyTick[ylabelPos=right](4){4}
```

But doesn't work.

[image]

Here is the whole code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=2,
       yunit=0.5,
       linewidth=0.03,
       tickwidth=0.03}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.775,-2)(1.775,6.8)
\psaxes[Dx=1,labels=x,xticksize=-4pt,Dy=2]{->}(0,0)(-1.77,0)(1.7,6.4)[$t$,0][$$,90]
\psyTick[ylabelPos=left](2){2}
\psyTick[ylabelPos=right](4){4}
\psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.05](-1.7,0)(-1,0)(-1,4)(0,4)(0,2)(1,2)(1,0)(1.6,0)
\rput(-0.6,4.5){$x_1(-2(t-1))$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to adjust the way `\psyTick` works since it currently doesn't support the placement:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\makeatletter
\def\psyTick@ii#1(#2)#3{{
  \pst@killglue
  \addbefore@par{arrows=-,linewidth=\psk@ytickwidth\pslinewidth}
  \use@par
  \psline(\pst@yticksizeB,#2)(\pst@yticksizeA,#2)
  \expandafter\ifx\psk@ylabelPos\tw@ %      2=right
    \rput[l]{#1}(! \psk@origin
                    \pst@number\pst@yticksizeB \pst@number\psylabelsep add
                    \pst@number\psxunit div #2){\psvlabel{#3}}\ignorespaces
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\psk@ylabelPos\@ne %    1=axis
      \rput{#1}(! \psk@origin
                      0 #2){\psvlabel{#3}}\ignorespaces
    \else % \psk@ylabelPos=\z@ 0=left
      \rput[r]{#1}(! \psk@origin
                      \pst@number\pst@yticksizeB \pst@number\psylabelsep add
                      \pst@number\psxunit div neg #2){\psvlabel{#3}}\ignorespaces
  \fi\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=2,
       yunit=0.5,
       linewidth=0.03,
       tickwidth=0.03}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.775,-2)(1.775,6.8)
  \psaxes[Dx=1,labels=x,xticksize=-4pt,Dy=2]{->}(0,0)(-1.77,0)(1.7,6.4)[$t$,0][$$,90]
  \psyTick[ylabelPos=l](2){2}
  \psyTick[ylabelPos=a](3){3}
  \psyTick[ylabelPos=r](4){4}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.05](-1.7,0)(-1,0)(-1,4)(0,4)(0,2)(1,2)(1,0)(1.6,0)
  \rput(-0.6,4.5){$x_1(-2(t-1))$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Instead of a fixed/single `\rput`, it's been adjusted to condition on the value of `\psk@ylabelPos` to decide whether the place the label on the `l`eft (`\z@`), `r`ight (`\tw@`) or on the `a`xis (`\@ne`).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=2,yunit=0.5,linewidth=0.03,tickwidth=0.03}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.775,-2)(1.775,6.8)
  \psaxes[Dx=1,labels=x,xticksize=-4pt,Dy=2]{->}(0,0)(-1.77,0)(1.7,6.4)[$t$,0][,90]
  \uput[180](0,2){2}  \uput[0](0,4){4}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.05](-1.7,0)(-1,0)(-1,4)(0,4)(0,2)(1,2)(1,0)(1.6,0)
  \rput(-0.6,4.5){$x_1(-2(t-1))$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]